# C how to allocate more than 2GB of memory

Tags: c, malloc

I am using code::blocks to compile a C program. The PC is: Windows 8.2 64b with 32GB of RAM + 32GB of swap if needed. I need 24GB to store intermediate values to have the program running fast enough (around X12 faster).

I need to allocate around 240 blocks of 100MB each.
The malloc returns NULL at the 19th block (there are some other small blocks) so total is 2GB.

Is there a way to compile/link the program to be able to allocate this memory?
An other tool than code::blocks? (I did it with Matlab, it works fine, no problem of memory but Matlab is really slower than compiled C).

Best regards.
Mich.

Comment: What is your program really doing? What are you supposed to use all that memory for?

Comment: You are compiling your app as a 32-bit app. They can only access a 4 GiB address space (2^32 bytes = 4 GiB), and 2 of those 4 GiB are reserved by Windows. You need to build it as a 64-bit app.

Comment: Code::Blocks is not the compiler. It is the IDE, using the compiler and options *you* choose. Which compiler in what version are you using?

Comment: This memory is for storing intemediate values of algorithms. Either I store them, or I recalculate them at each loop and this is very long.

Comment: I use minGW-32. I tried minGW64 without success: a tool error during linking, I probably badly configure code::blocks (not related to memory allocation). Will I be able to allocate more than 4GB with minGW64?

Comment: @Mich: Yes, the 64-bit version of minGW should be able to handle more than 2 GB of memory. However, when invoking the compiler, even if it is the 64-bit version of the compiler, you may have to enable a certain compiler option for it to use the 64-bit memory model, otherwise it may default to 32-bit. I don't know if this is the case, as I am unfamiliar with minGW. I suggest youi first try it with default settings and then, if you have the same problem, look for a compiler option to change the memory model.

Answer (score 1):

You need to build it as a 64 bit application, since 32 bit Windows applications have a restricted amount of 4 Gb addressable memory, lots of that being reserved for OS etc. Also, I don't think MinGW 32 bit is maintained any longer(?)

- Download and install Mingw64. http://mingw-w64.org
- In Codeblocks, Settings -> Compiler, pick the Toolchain executables tab.
- Specify the path, something like C:\Program Files\mingw-w64... (wherever you installed it)
- Click the button "auto detect". All gcc paths and tools should now be updated to point at the 64 bit installation. C compiler should be something like "x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe".

Comment: It seems that the mingw-w64 is a mingw32 for windows 64bits, not a 64 bits compiler...

Comment: Finally it works with x86_64-8.1.0-release-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0 revision.
Thanks a lot for the help.